# Problem with DateTime in Java

Tags: java, datetime, swt

i have used the `Swt DateTime`. But I get the problem that we cannot send `null` value through it. it is always declared. So i used the `nebulla dateChooserCombo`. it's a good one and i can send the null value too. But I faced the problem that unlike the `Swt DateTime` It is really difficult to s`witch form one year to another`.we have to move everymonth in it. We can explicitly enter the date through the `DateChoosercombo` but user may not know the `date Pattern` so it may be difficult for them. Is there any solution for this Problem.Please Do suggest me? is There any way we can enter `Null` value through swt DateTime?

Comment: Will `null` value, you mean that you don't want to have predefined date..?

Comment: @sorcerror null value means if the user do not want to supply any value into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Then you can add `checkbox` which will `enable` or `disable` the `DateTime` widget, and let user to decide if he/she wants to define the date or not..

Answer (score 1):

> but user may not know the date Pattern so it may be difficult for them

So tell them the pattern (e.g. in a `Label` or in the tooltip for `DateChooserCombo`).

> is There any way we can enter Null value through swt DateTime?

No.